# Python Eve fails to run on newly created droplet

Tags: python, python-2.7, digital-ocean, eve

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import eve
>>> from eve import Eve
>>> eve
<module 'eve' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/__init__.pyc'>
>>> app = Eve()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.validate_domain_struct()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 252, in validate_domain_struct
    raise ConfigException('DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.')
eve.exceptions.ConfigException: DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.
>>>
```

This happens and I cant seem to find out what the error is as this is a newly created Ubuntu image on Digital Ocean. Nothing is touched beside installing Python eve with pip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `settings.py` file on the same directory as your application, or you need to pass the path to `settings.py` with key `settings` in you app initialization. Check the [quickstart](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application) guide  for the minimal application.

The `settings.py` file should have your resources definition, which is the `DOMAIN` dictionary the error mentions.

Comment: This was the error, and for some reason I was blinded from seeing what is very obvious. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can mark the answer as correct to help others too. Thanks.